# Best practice override php file with child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a Wordpress Child Theme (mytheme-child) with the structure:

style.css
 
functions.php (empty)
folder
  >php.php

In the parent theme, the `php.php` file is included in the theme through the `functions.php` file, with the following entry:

```
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/folder/php.php' );
```

How can I override the parent `php.php` with the child theme `php.php`?

Comment: Is the `require_once()` hooked in with any action?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
The require_once is not hooked in with any action.
I want to use a child theme to keep the changes when the theme will be updated.

I tried to replace with no luck the php.php in the child functions.php through:
<?php
 if ( ! function_exists( 'php_modify' ) ) {
 function php_modify() {
 require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/folder/php.php' );
 }
 };
I searched a lot on google but not find an answer, remains a mystery.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Problem with mini-Markdown formatting. Sorry

Comment: You cannot prevent that inclusion while keeping the parent theme unmodified. Maybe you can prevent stuff that happens inside php.php? But we'd need more info about what php.php has in it.